# Referring to an installed jar in a Clojure project from the command line to java

Tags: java, clojure, jvm, javaagents

I need to pass the `-javaagent` attribute to my java command in production. In my machine this works just fine:

```
java -javaagent:/Users/pupeno/.m2/repository/com/newrelic/agent/java/newrelic-agent/3.19.2/newrelic-agent-3.19.2.jar -jar target/proclodo-spa-server-rendering.jar
```

but how do I do it without specifying a system-dependent full-path? Is it possible to not even mention version numbers, to make upgrades easier?

Comment: does it work if teh jar is in the current working directory and you specify only proclodo-spa-server-rendering.jar?

Comment: I don't want to have a jar in my version control tree, it's a big binary file instead of source code and it's out of my build system, so it won't get updated unless I remember to explicitly check for updates and do it.